# Multiprocessing deadlock in a customtkinter app

Tags: python, multiprocessing, customtkinter

I have created a customtkinter app for a data analysis. To increase speed I want to multiprocess one of the functions. When I do it deadlocks for some files but not others. The data structure passed to the multiprocessing function is a list of dictionaries. The dictionary values are strings or empty strings except for the 'Datetime' field which is a datetime object. I am running a MacBook M2 Pro Ventura 13.5.

The code:

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import csv
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY, YEARLY
csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import xlsxwriter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import colorsys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import Data_and_variables as dv
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

# The function to multiprocess
def process_episodes(episodes_array):
                  
     episodes_to_eval = episodes_array[0]
     start_date = episodes_array[1]
     end_date = episodes_array[2]
     items_to_evaluate = episodes_array[3]
     site_to_evaluate = episodes_array[4]
     subsite_to_evaluate = episodes_array[5]
     results_final = []
 
     if episodes_to_eval:
 
         for episode in episodes_to_eval:
 
             try:
                 if episode['Item Set'] in items_to_evaluate and episode['Site Description 1'] in site_to_evaluate and episode['Site Description 2'] in subsite_to_evaluate and episode not in results_final and start_date <= episode['Datetime'] <= end_date:
                     results_final.append(episode)
             except:
                 print(episode)
 
     return results_final    
 
 def summary_episode(episode_list, start_date, end_date, tests_to_evaluate, hospitals_to_evaluate, wards_to_evaluate):
 
     type_sorted = defaultdict(list)
 
     # Divide the episode list into chunks for multiprocessing
     num_cpus = cpu_count()
     chunk_size = len(episode_list) // num_cpus
     chunks = [(episode_list[i:i + chunk_size], start_date, end_date,  items_to_evaluate, site_to_evaluate, subsite_to_evaluate) for i in range(0, len(episode_list), chunk_size)]
 
     with Pool(processes=num_cpus) as pool:
         results_multi = pool.map(process_episodes, chunks)
 
     # Aggregate results
     results_out = []
     for result in results_multi:
         results_out.extend(result)
 
     # Type sorting
     for episode in results_out:
         try:
             results_available = False
             # dv.fields is a list of strings in the Data and variables file
             for field in dv.fields:
                 if episode[field] != '':
                     results_available = True
                     break
             if results_available:
                 type_sorted[episode['type']].append(episode)
         except:
            print(episode)
 
     return type_sorted


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # GUI components not interacting with multithreading function 
        ...
    
    # Function calling the multiprocessing function - called by button command
    def generate_data(self):
        # Check if variables assigned 
        summary_data = summary_episode(episode_list, start_date, end_date, tests_to_evaluate, hospitals_to_evaluate, wards_to_evaluate)
        # Downstream analysis - No multithreading 
        ...
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Things I have tried and further info:
Note: The code works fine without multiprocessing.

1. Checked that episode_list list of dicts is pickleable - They are
2. Used a Manager() object to update a shared list rather than have the process_episodes function return an object - still deadlock
3. Tried spawning processes as follows with no change - still deadlock:

```
# if multiprocessing.get_start_method(allow_none=True) is None:
#     multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

4. Tried using different numbers of processes - (1 process still deadlocks)
5. Tried adjusting chunk sizes - still deadlocks
6. Inspected the raw data - no difference between sets that work and sets that don't other than the time period they are from and the length of the list (but as noted, changing chunk sizes doesn't resolve the issue)
7. I added print(f'starting: {os.getpid()}') and print(f'end: {os.getpid()}') at the start and finish of the multiprocessor function - the issue seems to be after executing the code block and before starting the next chunk - (the code in process_episodes executes fine)

Edit: Python 3.11.

Comment: What exactly means "it deadlocks"? Have you checked (e. g. with `print`s) in `summary_episode` if e. g. `pool.map...` doesn't return or if the `with Pool...` block can't be left?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Does it happen without customtkinter? Have you checked the contents of the file where it happens? Does it happen every time for that file?

Comment: The pool.map function doesn't return. When placing print statements within the summary_episode function the data tuple is correctly passed to process_episodes and the chunks contain the data as expected, print statements before the pool.map function are reached but no print statements after the pool.map function are reached. print statements within process_episodes show that if the function is called it proceeds correctly so the issue seems to be a block between data transfer between the processes and the pool.map return object. Will create an MRE.